# Python reading file in binary, binary data to string?

Tags: python, string, binary

I'm trying to learn Python and currently doing some exercises online. One of them involves reading zip files.

When I do:

```
import zipfile
zp=zipfile.ZipFile('MyZip.zip')
print(zp.read('MyText.txt'))
```

it prints:

```
b'Hello World'
```

I just want a string with "Hello World". I know it's stupid, but the only way I could think of was to do:

```
import re
re.match("b'(.*)'",zp.read('MyText.txt'))
```

How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: @John, it makes it "b'Hello World'"

Comment: I'm dumbfounded that this didn't get flagged as a possible duplicate and closed in seconds.

Comment: Given that I sometimes feel that Python is growing too complex, and has grown too many conflicting ways of doing the exact same thing over the years, I am terribly pleased that we three produced textually the exact same answer to this question independently of each other. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to decode the raw bytes in the string into real characters. Try running `.decode('utf-8')` on the value you are getting back from `zp.read()` before printing it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems all three of you just about tied for the answer, but you got it first.

Answer (score 5):

You need to [decode the bytes to text](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) first.

```
print(zp.read('MyText.txt').decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 5):

Just [decode](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) the bytes:

```
print(zp.read('MyText.txt').decode('UTF-8'))
```